# Windows Share Permissions VS NTFS Permissions

Tags: windows, network-shares, ntfs, smb

Say I have a folder on Server1 called folder1 and I share folder1 and the Share permissions for that folder allow all users to read only, and then i create a subfolder in folder1 lets call it subfolder1,

Now the only permissions I can change on subfolder1 are the NTFS permissions, However if I want 1 specific user to have write access in subfolder1 id add that user to the NTFS perms of subfolder1 lets call the user John Doe,

Now when John Doe comes to write in that folder, Will the SMB Permisions of the share Stop him from writing to folder1 & subfolder1 as the share permissions only allow read access to all user or will John Doe be able to write to the sub folder.

Side Question

If Folder1 share permissions allowed everyone write access, but folder1s NTFS permisions denied everyone write access which would be enforced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most restrictive permissions are enforced.

See also:

- [Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178.aspx) – *Windows Server 2008*
- [Share permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784499(v=ws.10).aspx) – *Windows Server 2003*

Comment: How about the first question though, if there is strict perms on the root of the share folder do child folders follow suit even if the NTFS perms of the sub folder allow certain users full control?

Comment: @Shutupsquare:  You specify that you set the share permissions, so the answer is yes.  Share permissions apply to the entire contents of the file share regardless of the NTFS permissions of the actual directory on disk being shared or those of any subdirectories.  You need to set the share permissions such that all users who need it will have full access, and rely on NTFS permissions to provide the fine-grained control you desire.